# Custom DNS Server for dynamic TXT Records

Tags: python, dns

I am trying to do something DNS isn't really meant for, so I won't be surprised if this isn't possible. I have a domain, and I've set up an NS record, so I can resolve queries for subdomains using my own server. I need to dynamically generate TXT records based on what subdomain is being resolved. Is this possible, and if so, what library/software can I use? I'd prefer Python, but any language works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a [PowerDNS](https://www.powerdns.com/) pipe, written in bash, based on [xip.io](https://xip.io)'s [source code](https://github.com/basecamp/xip-pdns).